# Differentials in multivariate analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have read a number of books which define the derivative of a function $f:R^n\rightarrow R^m$ and they seem split 50;50. All define it as a linear transformation $D$ but some (e.g. James R. Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds) say $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-D(h)}{\mid h\mid}\rightarrow0$$others (e.g. Michael Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds)$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\mid f(x+h)-f(x)-D(h)\mid}{\mid h\mid}\rightarrow0$$the difference being the norm being taken of the numerator in the second one. (Some have an equivalent to the first as a Taylor Series).

Is there any significance to this difference? Thanks.

Comment: Nope.  One vector function approaches another if and only if the distance between them approaches zero.

Comment: My thoughts entirely. Then why make the definition more complicated by adding the norm?

Comment: The best definitions are the ones which make the theorems easy to prove.  And when proving statements about limits, you end up taking the norm either way.